# Qt application in kiosk mode

Tags: c++, qt, kde-plasma, kiosk

I need to start my qt application on desktop under windows and linux in kiosk mode. 
May I do it, using qt or special system calls? (not adjusting operation system)

Comment: Have you checked the KDE kiosk framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could look into the KDE iosk framework:

http://techbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/Kiosk/Introduction

This is basically written in Qt, and should be working both on Linux and Windows. If you face any troubles, you can at least take their code as a good and robust base.

Here you can find the first paragraph of the introduction inline for your convenience:

> The KDE Kiosk is a framework that has been built into KDE since version 3. It allows administrators to create a controlled environment for their users by customizing and locking almost any aspect of the desktop which includes the benign such as setting and fixing the background wallpaper, the functional such as disabling user log outs and access to the print system and the more security conscientious such as disabling access to a command shell.